# WPF binding to class and display validation errors

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I am trying to set up binding in a WPF page.  I am referencing this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-a-binding-in-code

I am creating my controls dynamically so I need to set all my binding and validation programatically.  I want to trigger the PropertyChanged event and call classes that will do validation on different properties on a form.  If the validation fails, I want to display the errors on my form using the validation template in my designer page.  What am I doing wrong?

My user class:

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _userName;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _userName; }
        //set
        //{
        //    _firstName = value;
        //    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        //    {
        //        throw new Exception("Customer name is mandatory.");
        //    }
        //}
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

My code behind that creates the controls dynamically:

```
 UserName= new TextPanel(); //TextStackPanel is a user control
 //make a new source
            ViewModelUser bindingObject = new ViewModelUser();
            //Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyDataProperty");
            Binding myBinding = new Binding("UserName");
            myBinding.Source = bindingObject;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(UserName, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);
            bindingObject.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChangedMine;
```

My xaml designer page has the following:

```
<Page.Resources>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="TextBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                          Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: _"I am creating my controls dynamically"_ -- that's your problem right there. Don't create UI objects in code. Use templating. And if you really want to do it the wrong way and expect the SO community to help, fix your question so it includes a good [mcve].

Comment: You are not setting `ValidatesOnDataErrors` property on your `Binding` object. Read more about that [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Data_Binding_ValidatesOnDataErrors)

Answer (score 0):

If you validate by throwing exceptions, you should set the `ValidatesOnExceptions` property of the `Binding` to `true`.

You also need to set the `Style` property of the `TextBox` control to your `Style`, and you may also want to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` for the setter to get called for each key stroke:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Style = FindResource("TextBoxInError") as Style };
User bindingObject = new User();
Binding myBinding = new Binding("UserName") { ValidatesOnExceptions = true, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };
myBinding.Source = bindingObject;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Note that you can't apply a `Style` with a `TargetType` of `TextBox` to a `UserControl`.